# Making a Div The Exact Size of A5 Paper

Tags: html, css, size

I'm producing a magazine and I want to publish the pages in a wesbite and want the div to be the same size as an **actual** piece of A5 paper.

So I found out that you can use CM and MM in CSS, but when I do that I find that doing `width:210mm;` ( Which is A5 in portrait ) gives me a smaller size than my peice of paper, by about 1CM, what's the deal and how do I get it to show up at Actual size?

Comment: When you say its smaller, do you mean it just appears smaller? this is because the size of your screen is not taken into effect.

Comment: So therefore, making a div 210mm doesn't actually make it 210mm?

Comment: It does as far as the code and fixed size media (printer) is concerned, but there is nothing that can make it a certain size on someone's screen because there is no way in knowing what size their screen is.

Comment: What I mean is, there's no way to give a true display measurement of 210mm. Do you know what the size in Pixels would be for displaying a 210mm image - Meaning that if I held the paper against the screen it would match exactly?

Comment: As I said, there is no way to do this since there is no way in knowing the persons physical screen size, pixel density varies screen to screen, there is no x pixles = y mm conversion.

Comment: Kinda sucks, but I guess I'll hace to find a way round it!

Comment: stick with what you are doing, no matter what you do it will look wrong on somebody's screen, but the way you are doing it if they decide to save or print, at least it will be correct dimensions.

Comment: I plan on letting them download it anyway, I just don't want to comprimise the quality of the text if it's shrunk down.

Comment: Well text is vector based so that wouldn't change anyway, and dont think of it as "shrunk down", because it isn't, the display you are seeing it on simply has a higher pixel density than the normal dpi used in print media.

Comment: Print media isn't my strong point, but I'm finding it hard to build a site to meet the requirements of my subjects - Putting text and images down on paper is much easier than formatting in code, hense why I'm opting for print media! Cheers for the details.